# Expand a ListView, which will displays messages

Tags: flutter, user-interface, listview

I'm trying to create a chat screen, everything works as fine, until I add a message into my message list and it has to be displayed on the screen. Then the app crashes with the following error:

```
RenderObject: RenderFlex#83717 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=430.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    size: MISSING
    direction: vertical
    mainAxisAlignment: start
    mainAxisSize: max
    crossAxisAlignment: center
    verticalDirection: down
    child 1: _RenderScrollSemantics#4f646 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
        constraints: MISSING
        semantic boundary
        size: MISSING
        child: RenderPointerListener#8b994 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: <none>
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            behavior: deferToChild
            listeners: signal
            child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#12b20 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                behavior: opaque
                gestures: <none>
                child: RenderPointerListener#29265 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                    parentData: <none>
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    behavior: opaque
                    listeners: down, panZoomStart
    child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#5dfd5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=1.0)
        child: RenderPositionedBox#eb861 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: <none>
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            alignment: Alignment.center
            textDirection: ltr
            widthFactor: expand
            heightFactor: expand
            child: RenderPadding#848c3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero
                textDirection: ltr
                child: RenderConstrainedBox#18c35 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=1.0)
    child 3: RenderConstrainedBox#61201 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=430.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
        child: RenderMouseRegion#90872 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: <none>
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            behavior: opaque
            listeners: enter, exit
            cursor: SystemMouseCursor(text)
            child: RenderTapRegion#245fa NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                behavior: deferToChild
                groupId: EditableText
                child: RenderIgnorePointer#c2f01 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                    parentData: <none>
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    ignoring: false
                    ignoringSemantics: null
    child 4: RenderConstrainedBox#0eb83 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=18.6)
```

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════ RenderBox was not laid out:
> RenderFlex#83717 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
> NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1972
> pos 12: 'hasSize'

Here is my `Widget build`:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(
          'Chat',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Chalet',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              fontSize: widget.deviceWidth * 0.06),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: whitePrimary,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListView(
                    children: [Text(_messages[index])],
                  );
                }),
          ),
          const Divider(height: 1.0),
          _buildTextComposer(),
          SizedBox(
            height: widget.deviceHeight * 0.02,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.deviceWidth,
      child: TextField(
        autofocus: true,
        controller: _textFieldController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: whitePrimary,
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.send_rounded, color: orangePrimary),
            onPressed: () {
              _sendMessage(_textFieldController.text);
            },
          ),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: widget.deviceWidth * 0.03),
          hintText: 'Write a message...',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, there are nested `ListView`s, your entire design is mainly a list view that contains other list views (messages) inside it.

in that case the message listview (inner list view) must have `shrikWrap : true` and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` .